# Store/List not reloading Sencha 1.1.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I've got a phonegap-wrapped sencha touch (v1.1.1) app that has a few stores, and a list.

The problem occurs after you're logged in as *"User1"*, and then log out and log back in as *"User2"*. The list won't refresh with the new account data fetched by the store proxy.

I'm currently attempting to call [`.refresh()`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/1.1.1/#!/api/Ext.List-method-refresh) on the `List` itself, which according to the docs will also cause the store to refresh its data (although, I'm manually doing that before hand anyway)

```
var sL = Ext.getCmp('AccountsList');
sL.refresh();
sL.scroller.scrollTo({x:0,y:0});
```

We've also tried to [`.sync()`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/1.1.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-sync) the stores with no results.

```
Ext.getStore('AccountsTransfersTo').sync();
Ext.getStore('AccountsTransfersFrom').sync();
Ext.getStore('AccountsStore').sync();
```

Any idea what the problem is, or has anyone run into something similar?

Answer (score 3):

`refresh` won't reload the store, it just grabs whatever is in the store and re-renders the view.

`sync` is for updating the store when you've got local changes and you're posting them to the server.

You need to call the [`load`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/1.1.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load) method on the store.

Comment: That is why i was asking for a example of the code, you need to recreate the store, or empty it completely,without the sync invoke, or just plainly recreate it :)

Comment: No, all you need to do is trigger a load. It makes a request to the server, when it comes back, it will fire an event that the list listens to and it will refresh itself.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a caching problem. or a state problem. 
a link:
http://html5wood.com/sencha-touch-difference-between-ext-get-and-ext-getcmp/

from the page: 
Sencha Touch: Difference between Ext.get() and Ext.getCmp()

Important: It returns the same element object due to simple caching on retrieving again. It means it returns wrong element on **second** time. Ext.fly() can be used for avoiding this problem.

hope it helps
mike.

Answer (score 0):

You may Load the store each time

```
var sL = Ext.getStore('AccountsTransfersTo')
sL.load();
sL.scroller.scrollTo({x:0,y:0});
```

or you may try to clear data form store and reload it again

```
var sL = Ext.getStore('AccountsTransfersTo')
sL.removeAll();
sL.load();
sL.scroller.scrollTo({x:0,y:0});
```

Comment: Remember that I'm using Sencha 1.1.1 -- there is no `removeAll()` or `load()` method for lists.